# Localization in ASP.NET never worked for me !

Tags: asp.net, localization, asp.net-2.0

I'm facing a strange issue, 
I'm trying to localize a website, so i converted it to a web application and generated resx file for each aspx and ascx file i have ( pagename.en.resx ..etc)

however the localization never worked with me. one thing to mention that when i open the resx files in the designer mode i find "Access Modifier" dropdown enabled on the upper right, on sample projects that works successfully i find the "Access Modifier" dropdown disable ?

Your suggestions are very much appreciated !

Comment: Stupid question: you mention pagename.en.resx, but are those really pagename.aspx.resx (for the default) and pagename.aspx.xx.resx for other languages? How did you generate the resx files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved ! the issue was as follows :
I defined resources files with language prefix : resourcefile.en.resx , resourcefile.jp.resx 
however ASP.NET requires a generic resource file like resourcefile.resx

Thank you all !

Answer (score 0):

- Try also declaring the culture:
- Make sure that your browser settings include English as a language.

If that doesn't help, can you post some of the code of your aspx/ascx file in which you use localization?